# How to get a particular string from a sentence in Android?

Tags: android

I stored my data in a [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database. The data which I stored is in the HTML tags, for example, "Who is a good leader?"

[image]

Actually, my task is to display a question and its related image. I kept my images in a drawable folder. Now when the question is displayed along with that the image it should also display. How do I achieve this task?

Comment: Why are you using HTML at all? You should have a column with the question and a column with the name of the image.

Comment: hi it is stored like that in db. Now I cant change...I am able to display the question and in code I am removing the html tags. But along with the question how can I display the image from drawable...Plz help me....will be thankful to you..

Comment: Hi i want to get the name of the image from the above html code...so that I can display that image from drawable folder

Answer (score 1):

If you really are constrained to parse html, a series of substring and indexOf calls will work assuming you have unique non-repeating markers in what you are parsing.

You could for example do this:

```
    //Set markers that will act as unique identifiers for when the image name begins/ends
    final String beginningMarker = "src=\"";
    final String endingMarker = "\"";

    //Define what html we are parsing
    String html = "<img alt=\"\" width=\"248\" height=\"170\" src=\"/test/image1.png\" />";

    //Use our markers to find out the locations in the html where the image name begins/ends
    int imgStringStartIndex = html.indexOf(beginningMarker) + beginningMarker.length();
    int imgStringEndIndex = html.indexOf(endingMarker, imgStringStartIndex);

    //Use the locations we just found to extract the image name
    String imageName = html.substring(imgStringStartIndex, imgStringEndIndex);
    System.out.println(imageName);
```